# Mapping all routes and its http methods in Goji

Tags: go, routes, goji

I would like to map each route and it's request type (GET, POST, PUT, ...) to generate something like a sitemap.xml in JSON for my restful API.

Goji uses functions to create a new route. I could store the paths and handlers in a map.

My approach would be something like this, except that the compiler gives the following initialization loop error, because `sitemap` and `routes` refer to each other (the routemap contains the handler sitemap that should marhsall itself).

```
main.go:18: initialization loop:
    main.go:18 routes refers to
    main.go:41 sitemap refers to
    main.go:18 routes
```

Can this be achieved in a more idiomatic way?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/zenazn/goji"
    "github.com/zenazn/goji/web"
)

var routes = []Route{
    Route{"Get", "/index", hello},
    Route{"Get", "/sitemap", sitemap},
}

type Route struct {
    Method  string          `json:"method"`
    Pattern string          `json:"pattern"`
    Handler web.HandlerType `json:"-"`
}

func NewRoute(method, pattern string, handler web.HandlerType) {
    switch method {
    case "Get", "get":
        goji.DefaultMux.Get(pattern, handler)
    case "Post", "post":
        goji.DefaultMux.Post(pattern, handler)
        // and so on...
    }

}

func hello(c web.C, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Hello world"))
}

func sitemap(c web.C, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // BUG: sitemap tries to marshall itself recursively
    resp, _ := json.MarshalIndent(routes, "", "    ")
// some error handling...
    w.Write(resp)
}

func main() {

    for _, r := range routes {
        NewRoute(r.Method, r.Pattern, r.Handler)
    }

    goji.Serve()
}
```

Comment: Usually I do so but I don't wanted to keep the example as simple as possible. Thanks for the tip with `init()`

Comment: wrt errors, that's fine; it's just I see that too often in "real" code, probably from niave people cut-n-pasting, which is why I sometimes point it out and I prefer to simplify examples to no less than a comment about checking the error (i.e. `// … handle error …` or somesuch)

Comment: I added an annotion.

Comment: Would you stick with the switch-case approach?

Comment: I don't know/use `goji` so I'm unfamilar with it. However, your two cases call functions with identical signatures so perhaps you could consider using either an interface or a `type x func(string, web.Handler)`, either as the argument or as a map entry (or a field of `Route`) or whatever. As this may be getting off-topic from the question or too chatty we could take this to [chat] if you liked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to avoid the initialization loop is to break the loop by delaying one of the initializations.

E.g.:

```
var routes []Route

func init() {
    routes = []Route{
        Route{"Get", "/index", hello},
        Route{"Get", "/sitemap", sitemap},
    }
}
```

With this change your code compiles.

[Edit after [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/23438971#23438971):]

A fully edited and runnable example that also addresses your question about the `switch` follows:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/zenazn/goji"
    "github.com/zenazn/goji/web"
)

var routes []Route

func init() {
    // Initialzed in init() to avoid an initialization loop
    // since `routes` refers to `sitemap` refers to `routes`.
    routes = []Route{
        Route{"Get", "/index", hello},
        Route{"Get", "/sitemap", sitemap},
        //Route{"Post", "/somewhereElse", postHandlerExample},
    }
}

type Route struct {
    Method  string          `json:"method"`
    Pattern string          `json:"pattern"`
    Handler web.HandlerType `json:"-"`
}

var methods = map[string]func(web.PatternType, web.HandlerType){
    "Get":  goji.Get,
    "Post": goji.Post,
    // … others?
}

func (r Route) Add() {
    //log.Println("adding", r)
    methods[r.Method](r.Pattern, r.Handler)
}

func hello(c web.C, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Hello world"))
}

func sitemap(c web.C, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    resp, err := json.MarshalIndent(routes, "", "    ")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Can't generate response properly.", 500)
        return
    }

    w.Write(resp)
}

func main() {
    for _, r := range routes {
        r.Add()
    }
    goji.Serve()
}
```

Available as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/dchapes/cedcfbaf31d731127cff).

I'll note there is nothing wrong with a switch like you had it,
and in this case if there are only two methods a map may be overkill.
A [previous version of the example](https://gist.github.com/dchapes/cedcfbaf31d731127cff/0d56ee3df367f7d7e454dedcaa7e1ff343daa10e)
didn't use a map and explicitly specified both the function and method name (which were expected to match).

Also this version doesn't check for invalid method names (which if `routes` is always hard coded and never changed at runtime is reasonable). It would be straight forward to do `fn, ok := methods[r.Method]` and do something else if/when `!ok` if desired.